# How to serve content from AWS CloudFront when URL contains some random parameters like auth token?

Tags: c#, java, amazon-web-services, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

Not terribly familiar with CF so please point me to the right direction. In order to utilize AWS CF, do my URLs need to look the same? In other words, when serving a static image, the URL string is the same - just some domain and path to an image. However in customer based case, my URLs contain auth token or some other random information that is irrelevant to the content itself. Is it still possible to utilize Amazon's CDN?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure CF to ignore query strings in which case it will only cache based on the base part of the URL.

Query strings can be useful as a means of invaliding the cache should the file change.

Comment: In reality it's .net web service call. So I can't ignore all of them unfortunately. Some of them are used to actually identify the content.